# find control by name with linq

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, telerik, ribbon

Hello folks is it possible to find a controll by its name via Linq?

I can iterate thorught contorl collection via for each

```
foreach (RibbonTab t in testRibbon.CommandTabs)
                    {
                        if (t.Name == tab.Name)
                        {
                            blnFound= true;

                        }
                    }
```

The idea is to save memory.
I create telerik ribbon tabs dynamically and i want to see if the tab is there then don't create it also i want to check the ribbonbar if it has specific RadRibbonBarGroup and RadButtonElement by name same as for ribbontab so i dont make duplicates.

Sorry if i complicated a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool found = testRibbon.CommandTabs.Cast<RibbonTab>().Any(t => t.name == tab.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with Linq-to-WindowsForms. See the following article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LinqToTree.aspx#linqforms

You can find all the controls with a given name like so:

```
var namedControls= this.Descendants()
                       .Where(ctrl => ctrl.Name="NameToFind");
```